# PHP extract values from a string

Tags: php, regex, substr

I'm processing records in PHP and was wondering if there is an efficient method to pull out the genre: values from each of the following records.  genre: can be anywhere in the string.

In the following string I need to pull out the word "alternative" (last word)

```
[media:keywords] => upc:00602527365589,Records,mercury,artist:Neon 
 Trees,Alternative,trees,neon,genre:alternative
```

In the following string I need to pull out "Latin / Pop,latino,Pop"

```
[media:keywords] => genre:Latin / Pop,latino,Pop,upc:00602527341217,artist:Luis 
 Fonsi,luis,universal,Fonsi,Latin
```

In the following record I need to pull out "other"

```
[media:keywords] => upc:793018101530,andy,razor,Other,tie,genre:other,artist:Andy 
McKee,McKee,&
```

In the following record I need to pull out "rock,flotsam,jetsam"

```
[media:keywords] => and,upc:00602498572061,genre:rock,flotsam,jetsam,artist:Flotsam 
And Jetsam,rock,geffen
```

I'm pulling my hair out on this (what is left anyway).

Comment: I'm no good with Regex but I done this `(genre:).*(?=.*\:)` is the max I can do. If anyone can evolve that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regular expression coupled with [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
~\bgenre:(.+?)(?=(,[^:,]+:|$))~
```

Your desired result will be in the first element of the matches array (paremeter 3).

Comment: Thanks Dr.  I did a test on 300 records...all matched up perfectly..now i hope the next 50k do hah...really thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I shall use a strpos to define where the genre starts. The only problem you have is where to end it because you do not have a delimeter. I should use the known other keywords like "upc","artist" etc to check if the string needs to be cut of at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a bit of pattern detection. You are always looking for the fixed `genre:` followed by one or more words or phrases, neither of which may itself contain a `:`

So this might suffice:

```
preg_match('~\bgenre:(,?[^:,]+(?=,|$))+~', $media_keywords, $match);
print $match[1];
```

Comment: This regular expression does not work.  For the first example, it matches "alternative" like it's supposed to, but for the others it matches ",upc", ",artist", and ",artist", respectively.

Comment: What you probably meant was `~\bgenre:((,?[^:,]+)+)~` instead, so that `$match[1]` contained all the repeated genres.  However, even this is incorrect, as `[^:,]+` will still match the next "category".  For example, "upc" or "artist".

Comment: Nah, it stops at `,Pop`. But the extra capture group is unavoidable.

Comment: Your new regex, `~\bgenre:(,?[^:,]+(?=,|$))+~` still matches incorrectly.  It matches "alternative", ",Pop", "other", and ",jetsam".

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

From the PHP Documentation for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

So you can just use `$findme = "alternative"`

Answer (score 0):

your problem with parsing this string is that you don't have normal delimiter and/or quotes (i.e. comma separates fields, but may be as well included in a field - it's the same problem that exist with CSV files without quotes).

If performance does not matter a lot for you I would suggest parsing it in more bullet proof way, like make some assumption about what is a key (like artist, genre, ups, etc.) and introduce some normal delimiter, the proof of concept code would be: (i have left echoes so you can see whats happening)

```
$string = "genre:Latin / Pop,latino,Pop,upc:00602527341217,artist:Luis Fonsi,luis,universal,Fonsi,Latin";
//introduce a delimiter
$delimiter = '|';
$withDelimiter = preg_replace('/([a-z]+):/', $delimiter . '$0', $string);
echo $withDelimiter . "\n";

$fields = explode($delimiter, $withDelimiter);
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (strlen($field)) {
        echo $field . "\n";

        list ($key, $valueWithPossiblyTrailingComma) = explode(':', $field);    

        if ($key === 'genre') {
            $genre = rtrim($valueWithPossiblyTrailingComma, ',');
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $genre;
```

you can make it work in nearly all cases, and it allows you to find any key not only genre - but it's performance will be low.

I have made following assumptions about your string:

- it is a list of key => value pairs delimited by colon and concatenated with comma
- key may have only [a-z] characters